# Condition for two curves to intersect

Tags: calculus, coordinate-systems, algebraic-curves

> The curves are $$ y = \log_n |x|$$  $$ y = mx^2 + k$$
>
> For $0<n<1$ and $m<0$, what are the conditions of k for solutions to
>   $\log_n |x| = mx^2 + k$?

I tried to apply the logic that for solutions, the integral area between the curves must be > 0, from where after simplification I got $$ (b-a)[(b^2 + ab + a^2)m*ln(n) + 3k*ln(n) + 3] > ln\Biggl(\frac{|b|^{3b}}{|a|^{3a}}\Biggl)$$ where a, -a and b, - b are the points of intersection and |b|>|a|

Now, there can be three cases:

**a and b both over x-axis** $\implies$ k > 0 $\implies$ R.H.S. > 1

**b over x axis and a below it** $\implies$ k>0 $\implies$ R.H.S. > 1

**a and b both below x axis** $\implies$ 1>R.H.S.>0$\implies$  |ab|>1

Therefore, L.H.S. in all the three cases > 0 (wherein we can exclude the (b-a) part as it is always positive)

I'm stuck at this point. Help?
$$----$$
For solving further, I had replaced ln(n) with $\frac{(ln|ab|)}{m(a^2 + b^2) + 2k}$

Comment: consider the function $g(x)=\log _n x-m x^2$ for $x>0$. $k$ must be greater than the minimum of $g$

Comment: @Lozenges Since it is $\log_n |x|$, I don't think x>0 needs to be mentioned. Also, g(x)=k, and your statement means that k has a minimum value, above which there will always be 4 solutions... which can already be inferred from the graph, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: ....... Anyone?

Comment: Let $\left(x_0,k_0\right)$ be the minimum point. We have four solutions for $k>k_0$, two solutions for $k=k_0$, no solutions for $k<k_0$. Here $k_0=g\left(x_0\right)$. To find $x_0$ solve $g'(x)=0$. Done.

Comment: Yess, thank you so much, finally got it :)